Is there a way to disable drag selection in a DataGridView without disabling MultiSelect?
I am trying to display data in a table format and allow users to pick cells. However, they should only be able to pick 1 cell per column, which is why MultiSelect is required.
Example of 1 cell selection per column:

Currently, I have an implementation for allowing only 1 selected cell per column, which works until I try to drag select.
Example of drag selection:

From what I've seen, there is no built-in way to disable drag selection if MultiSelect needs to be enabled.
Here is the current implementation:
private void TableViewer_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Skip headers
    if (e.RowIndex \< 0 || e.ColumnIndex \< 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Disable multiple selections within the same column
    var selectedCells = gridViewTableViewer.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in selectedCells)
    {
        if (cell.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            // Another cell in the same column has already been selected.
            cell.Selected = false;
        }
    }
}

I've tried keeping track of the left mouse button (LMB) being held down/pressed through the CellMouseDown and MouseUp events + a TableViewer.ClearSelection() inside the CellMouseEnter event (if LMB is being held down):
(TableViewer is a DataGridView)
private void TableViewer_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown)
    {
        TableViewer.ClearSelection();
    }
}

private void TableViewer_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = true;

    ...
}

private void TableViewer_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = false;
}

Any help would be appreciated - thank you so much!

A simple way, without creating custom Columns, would be handling the CellMouseDown and CellMouseUp events. In the former, add Capture = true;, in the latter, Capture = false;. This prevents a drag selection from happening, but may also change the way you enter edit mode, since double-clicking the Cell does nothing (the DGV doesn't have the mouse capture). Of course, you can press the dedicated key (F2), or any other character key to enter text

If you press and hold the Shift key modifier, no more cells will be selected and only the preselected cells will be dragged and remain selected. You don't need to write additional code.

@dr.null Maybe I'm missing something. How does that enforce OP's rule that "they should only be able to pick 1 cell per column" when dragging over cells that by default DGV behavior are being selected as "multiple cells per column"? The rule has to hold no matter what. And yes, having the DGV meet this non-standard requirement will require writing code.

@IV. The question is how to drag the selected cells or something else? Allowing only 1 cell/column/same or different rows is an easy task I believe. Let me read again.

@IV. You're Right.

@dr.null thanks, though, your comment helped me make my answer a little clearer about how it addresses the question.

@Matt this is a great question and I'd ▲ it again if I could. I think it took all of us a little bit to wrap our heads around what you're doing, which as I now understand it is a hybrid that acts like single selection in any given column, but acts like a multiple selection in the sense that every column is allowed to have a single selection which turns out to be a pretty neat trick. Just letting you know that I'm done messing with the answer now, and thanks for your patience while I figured out exactly what the spec was supposed to be.

Your post states:

they should only be able to pick 1 cell per column.

As your image shows, the problem is that dragging over multiple cells with MultiSelect enabled is going to break that rule by selecting "multiple cells per column".

In other words, we need to be able to preview when the cell selection is changing, and have some criteria for whether to allow the change to occur. The DataGridView.SetSelectedCellCore method is an ideal place to do this, and since this is protected and fires no event, it's necessary to make a lightweight extended class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView.
The main feature of DataGridViewEx is to be able to SingleSelectInColumn(int columnIndex, int rowIndex). Your code is correct that this needs to happen OnCellMouseDown. But to fix your problem with the drag-select, we also need to call it OnCellMouseEnter.
Meanwhile, the overridden SetSelectedCellCore method inspects _allowedColumn and if it's set, disallows attempted changes to any other column.
I used the minimal test code shown below to verify that this works as intended.
class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var cellToggle = 
            e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 ?
            this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] : null;
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && cellToggle?.Selected == true)
        {
            cellToggle.Selected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            BeginInvoke(() => SingleSelectInColumn(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex));
        }
        // CRITICAL - Do 'not' call base class method!
    }
    private void SingleSelectInColumn(int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            _allowedColumn = columnIndex;
            if (columnIndex >= 0 && rowIndex >= 0)
            {
                var cellsInColumn = 
                    Rows
                    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Select(_ => _.Cells[columnIndex]); 

                foreach (
                    var cell in
                    cellsInColumn )
                {
                    var sbSelected = cell.RowIndex == rowIndex;
                    if(!Equals(cell.Selected, sbSelected))
                    {
                        cell.Selected = sbSelected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _allowedColumn = null;
        }
    }
    public int? _allowedColumn = null;
    protected override void OnCellMouseEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellMouseEnter(e);
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            BeginInvoke(()=> SingleSelectInColumn(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex ));
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        // CRITICAL - We have to put this back the way we found it!
        _allowedColumn = null;
    }
    protected override void OnCellMouseLeave(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellMouseLeave(e);
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // CRITICAL - For example if the mouse is dragged outside the control.
            _allowedColumn = int.MinValue;
        }
    }
    protected override void SetSelectedCellCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool selected)
    {
        if (_allowedColumn is int validColumnIndex)
        {
            if(!Equals(columnIndex, validColumnIndex))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        base.SetSelectedCellCore(
            columnIndex,
            rowIndex,
            selected);
    }
}


You would then just manually edit your MainForm.Designer.cs file, substituting DataGridViewEx for DataGridView in two places.

Test Code
This routine simply populates the DataGridView with some rows to test. Then, in a continuous motion, the drag select is tested to ensure that the "one cell per column" rule is respected.

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
            
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            Records.AddNew();
        }
    }
    BindingList<Record> Records { get; } = new BindingList<Record>();
}
    
public class Record
{
    static int _debugCount = 1;
    public Record()
    {
        col1 = col2 = col3 = _debugCount ++;
    }

    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public int col2 { get; set; }
    public int col3 { get; set; }
}


Clone

Wow, thank you so much for such a detailed answer. It works perfectly.
Note for future viewers: If you're using an older .NET version, you may get a "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" on the BeginInvoke()s. To fix this, just wrap the lambda in a new Action().
